# How do you get the UIKit coordinates of an ARKit feature point?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit

I have an ARSCNView and I am tracking feature points in the scene. How would I get the 2D coordinates of the feature points (as in the coordinates of that point in the screen) from the 3D world coordinates of the feature point?

(Essentially the opposite of sceneView.hitTest)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting a point from 3D space (usually camera or world space) to 2D view (pixel) space is called *projecting* that point. (Because it involves a [projection transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection) that defines how to flatten the third dimension.)

ARKit and SceneKit both offer methods for projecting points (and unprojecting points, the reverse transform that requires extra input on how to extrapolate the third dimension).

Since you're working with `ARSCNView`, you can just use the [`projectPoint`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscenerenderer/1524089-projectpoint) method. (That's inherited from the superclass `SCNView` and defined in the `SCNSceneRenderer` protocol, but still applies in AR because ARKit world space is the same as SceneKit world/scene/rootNode space.) Note you'll need to convert back and forth between `float3` and `SCNVector3` for that method.

Also note the returned "2D" point is still a 3D vector — the `x` and `y` coordinates are screen pixels (well, "points" as in UIKit layout units), and the third is a relative depth value. Just make a `CGPoint` from the first two coordinates for something you can use with other UIKit API.

BTW, if you're using ARKit without SceneKit, there's also a [`projectPoint`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arcamera/2923538-projectpoint) method on `ARCamera`.